# How to get a feature with a srsName?

Tags: wfs, getfeature, autodesk

This is a duplicate asked on [AutoDesk Forum](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-MapGuide-Enterprise/How-to-GetFeature-with-srsCode/td-p/.UNHczW9lGCg).

If I form a request like this:

```
http://usalvwdgis1/mapserver2013/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=2&FID=47403&TYPENAME=Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE
```

I get a valid response:

```
<gml:featureMember>
  <Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE>
    <Water:FID>78935</Water:FID>
    <Water:Geometry>
      <gml:Point>
        <gml:pos>498289.041000 5459452.306000</gml:pos>
      </gml:Point>
    </Water:Geometry>
  </Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE>
</gml:featureMember>
```

But if I add a srsName to the request I get the *exact* same response:

```
http://usalvwdgis1/mapserver2013/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=2&TYPENAME=Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE&srsName=EPSG:26910     
http://usalvwdgis1/mapserver2013/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=2&TYPENAME=Water:WA_LARGE_VALVE&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326
```

But I expect to see the results in the requests coordinate system.  Is my request incorrectly formed (maybe add 'urn:x-ogc:def:crs' before the code)?

Answer (score 3):

The [OGC WFS 1.1.0 Specification](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=8339) tells us that:

> The optional srsName attribute of the  element is used to specify a specific WFS-supported SRS to be used for returned feature geometries. Its value may be the <DefaultSRS> or any of the <OtherSRS> values listed for the feature type in WFS capabilities document.

and

> Any valid URI value can be assigned to the srsName attribute. However,
>   in order to enhance interoperability, a web feature service must be
>   able to process srsName attribute values with the following format
>   models:
>
> - EPSG:<EPSG code>
> - http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#<EPSG code>
> - urn:EPSG:geographicCRC:<epsg code>

So if AutoDesk is fully compliant to the standard it should work with the syntax you have used.

However if your WFS GetCapabilities response uses a URN syntax to define the DefaultSRS or OtherSRS that it supports, it would probably be wise to use those URNs rather than the shortened form in your request.

The other thing that you need to bear in mind is that you can only make requests for SRS that are listed in the GetCapabilities response, so if neither EPSG:26910 or EPSG:4326 are listed in your service, you cannot request them. If you do make a request for an SRS that is not listed (supported), a service may do one of two things, that is, either throw an error, or ignore the SRS and return the default projection.

The default response you show is not using degrees as coordinates, so I know that [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326) is not the default projection, is it supported?